# Nodemon with flag --legacy-watch not working with docker Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, ubuntu, nodemon

I have a small web server that respond with "Hello World" in my docker.

But when developing (and change the response to something like "Hello World!!!"), I can not get it to reload on save.

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "nodemon", "--legacy-watch", "server.js" ]
```

I have to rebuild the image to have it changed. `--legacy-watch` or `-L` won't do the trick.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Can you use Node without Docker for this use case?  Change the `CMD` to something like `node server.js` so that you can `docker build` and `docker run` the image for eventual deployment, but it will have the same code that you've built, tested, and debugged locally.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need to use volumes. By default, Docker does not updates the image file system according to the changes you are making in your FS. Volumes allow you to keep container FS and local FS in sync.

You can read in detail about volumes [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)